# How to show dropdown list when an image is clicked in react-native-modal-dropdown

Tags: react-native

I want to implement react-native-modal-dropdown functionality in my app,

here is the code

```
      <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
                    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{Strings.Location}</Text>
                    <View style={styles.input}>

                        <Image
                            style={styles.mapIcon}
                            source={require('../assets/map_pic_icon.png')}
                        />

                        <ModalDropdown

                            onSelect={(index, value) => { this.setState({ selected: value }) }}
                            options={['option 1', 'option 2', 'option 3', 'option 4']}
                            defaultValue={Strings.Gaston}
                            dropdownTextStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', fontSize: 18, color: colors.black }}/*Style here*/
                            textStyle={{ fontSize: 18, color: colors.gunmetal, alignSelf: 'flex-start', marginLeft: 10 }}
                            dropdownStyle={{ flex: 1, width: '90%', marginVertical: 10, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: colors.light_gray }}
                            style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%', backgroundColor: colors.white, justifyContent: 'center' }}
                        />
                        <Image
                            style={styles.iconStyle}
                            source={require('../assets/down_arrow_blue.png')}
                        />
                    </View>
                </View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: colors.white,
    },

    viewStyle: {
        margin: 10,
    },

    input: {
        height: 50,
        width: '100%',
        marginTop: 8,
        borderRadius: 2,
        borderColor: colors.light_gray,
        fontSize: 20,
        borderWidth: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-around'
    },
    iconStyle: {
        margin: 20,
        alignSelf: 'flex-end'
    },
    mapIcon: {
        margin: 10,
        alignSelf: 'center',
    },


});
```

using this code my screen looks like this

[image]

my problem is when i click on  blue color down arrow  image then drodown is not opening it is only opening when i click on text .

How to solve this

And one more issue is dropdown width is not aligning properly to parent.

It is coming like this

[image]

Can anyone please tell me how to show dropdown list when icon is clicked and how to align the drodownlist list width properly.